# Java - instantiating an unknown number of entities

Tags: java

I have an entity called Person, in which there are 2 parameters: Name and Age.
I don't know how many entities I might need, this how I use an predefined number of entities:

```
private Person[] person = new Person[3]; //With this I'm saying that there will be only 3...
```

Now, I dont know how many Persons will i have so, how can I do this using a List?

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>(); //random guessing
```

Comment: Do you mean you have an _object_ called Person?

Comment: Look at the implementations of List. And then according to your requirements go for appropriate concrete implementation of List. For a start go with ArrayList.
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a concrete implementation of `List`, like this:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, List is what you're looking for. ArrayList is the actual class you'd want to instantiate.

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
personList.add(new Person());
```

Then, if you wanted to get an array out of this, you can use the toArray method, but you'll need to add a cast.

```
Person[] personArray = (Person[]) personList.toArray();
```